# Navigation drawer not coming on activities except on first activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have three activities `MainActivity`, `SecondActivity`, `ThirdActivity`
Instead of fragments I'm using activities.

I made a navigation drawer for `MainActivity`. `SecondActivity` and `ThirdActivity` extended `MainActivity`.

```
MainActivity[

//NavigationDrawer code

]

SecondActivity Extends MainActivity[

]

ThirdActivity Extends MainActivity[

]
```

Drawers icon shows up in Second and Third Activity but its not opening up on clicking it.

please help me.

Comment: add code of MainActivity into ur question.

Comment: @PRAVIN please go through my code  http://goo.gl/GGSLHh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in your MainActivity as

```
public void openDrawer()
{
     mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

So you can access it from your any of activity

```
ThirdActivity extends MainActivity
 {
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //Set button clicki event and just call function of mainActivity               
    openDrawer();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got three different activities, so you have to add the drawer in the layouts of each of these activities. A more suitable solution would be to use fragments instead of an activity

Comment: please go through my code and suggest
http://goo.gl/H5xd9m  in every activity i used drawer code on extending its not working as u said i have used drawer layout in all three xml files it working but i dont want to use same code in all three java files how can i avoid this please help me

Comment: As I said, the best way to avoid using the same code in all java files is use fragments!

Comment: right now i cant change my entire code to fragments so i am proceeding with activities. is there any way other than fragments like inheritance etc